# Python logging puts additional newline when writing to file (but not to stdout)

Tags: python, logging, newline

I set up a Python (3.6.5) logger on Windows 7 to write simultaneously to file and stdout like this:

```py
def __filehandler() -> logging.FileHandler:
    filehandler = logging.FileHandler(LOGFILE, encoding="cp932")
    filehandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fformatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s: %(name)-13s: %(levelname)-8s: %(message)s")
    filehandler.setFormatter(fformatter)

    return filehandler


def __streamhandler() -> logging.StreamHandler:
    streamhandler = logging.StreamHandler()
    streamhandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    sformatter = logging.Formatter("%(name)-13s: %(levelname)-8s: %(message)s")
    streamhandler.setFormatter(sformatter)

    return streamhandler


def getlogger(calling_module_name: str) -> logging.Logger:
    logger = logging.getLogger(calling_module_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(__filehandler())
    logger.addHandler(__streamhandler())

    return logger
```

and then use it calling `logger.info(some_text)`

Stdout **looks like expected**:

```
mymodule: INFO    : Reading file #1/2, line #42/164: /****************************************************************************/
mymodule: INFO    : Writing file #1/2, line #42/164: /****************************************************************************/
mymodule: INFO    : Reading file #1/2, line #43/164:
mymodule: INFO    : Writing file #1/2, line #43/164:
mymodule: INFO    : Reading file #1/2, line #44/164:
mymodule: INFO    : Writing file #1/2, line #44/164:
```

But in the corresponding file **there are additional, unaccounted for newlines**:

```
2019-05-17 12:21:11,824: mymodule: INFO    : Reading file #1/2, line #42/164: /****************************************************************************/

2019-05-17 12:21:11,824: mymodule: INFO    : Writing file #1/2, line #42/164: /****************************************************************************/
2019-05-17 12:21:11,824: mymodule: INFO    : Reading file #1/2, line #43/164: 

2019-05-17 12:21:11,824: mymodule: INFO    : Writing file #1/2, line #43/164: 

2019-05-17 12:21:11,824: mymodule: INFO    : Reading file #1/2, line #44/164: 

2019-05-17 12:21:11,839: mymodule: INFO    : Writing file #1/2, line #44/164:
```

Changing `filehandler = logging.FileHandler(LOGFILE, encoding="cp932")` to `filehandler = logging.FileHandler(LOGFILE)` has no effect.

The added newlines are detrimental to log's clarity and unnecessarily inflate its size. Any ideas what is happening here?

Comment: Are you running this code on Windows?  Could it be that newlines are converted to `'\r\n'` but you are viewing the log in an application that treats that sequence as as two newline characters?

Comment: Yes, I'm on Windows (I've updated the question). Reading the log in IPython shell (within Git Bash) with `for line in file: print(repr(line))` shows there are actually double newlines (`\n\n`) and not (`\r\n`) between the lines of text.